# Fast structure identification

Tags: data-structures, fingerprinting

I'm wondering about a smart and efficient way to tell a data structure from another.

If we assume data structures are stored as JSON trees in an array, the problem can be summarized as follows:

```js
[
    // Type 1
    {
        "name" : "value",
        "key" : "other_value",
    },
    // Type 2
    {
        "name" : "value",
        "key" : "other_value",
        "another_key" : "another_value",
        "data" : [
            { "a" : 1 },
            { "a" : 2 },
            // ...
        ]
    },
    // ...
]
```

Possible solutions I've come up with include:

1. Hand-made hard-coded rules like `if 'another_key' in data`, but that would be heavy to maintain when the number of data entries and the amount of different types grows.
2. Structure fingerprinting: hashing the whole tree except for the leaves and using the hash to identify a unique data structure. This would be a good solution if the number of entries in `"data" : [ ... ]` were fixed.
3. Schemas ([JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/), [XML Schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema), ...), but I feel this is a little "over-engineered" for the problem in question.

Are you aware of any better method to solve this and similar problems?

---

Edit: more examples

```cs
class Book {
    public int id;
    public string title;
}

class BookWithAuthor : Book {
    public string author;
}

class BookWithMultipleAuthors : BookWithAuthor {
    public string[] moreAuthors; // array structure
}

class BookWithSequel : BookWithAuthor {
    public Book sequel; // list structure
}

class BookWithSequelsAndSpinoffs : BookWithAuthor {
    public BookWithAuthor[] sequels;
    public Book[] spinoffs;
    // tree structure
}
```

Imagine having a (broken) serialization of a `Book[] books` with no information about what type of book it is and need to recover the original format (or something equivalent).

Also, I've used C# for the sake of simplicity, this is a general question.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by 'different'? or give 1/2 more examples? the question isn't really clear

Comment: @ShihabShahriar I've added an example as requested ;)

Comment: You get to the syntax tree vis-avis parsing the token output from a Lex (a.k.a. Scan). Add a type identifier to the AST node at that point in time.

Comment: @FrankC. Thanks for the hint, maybe I haven't been clear: I get the "AST" from an external source, that was just an attempt to better describe the problem, I'm not writing a compiler ;) The structure I get somehow resembles an AST, but at this point I think the example is misleading and I should remove it.